# Axios: trigger cancel interceptor request from UI

Tags: vue.js, axios

How would I trigger an axios interceptor request from the UI?

The two issues:

1. integrating the axios.Cancel correctly inside the request correctly.
2. getting a button to trigger the cancel.

```js
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
let cancel;

instance.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    if (cancel) {
      cancel();
    }
    config.cancelToken = new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
      cancel = c;
    });
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

```html
<!-- some button -->
<template>
  <button @click="cancelRequest">Cancel</button>
</template>

<script>
methods: {
  cancelRequest() {
    // trigger request 
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do this from an interceptor. How would this lone button element get access to the cancel token?

Comment: I did a `window.location.reload()`. I'd like to learn the proper way, but this works for now. :/

Comment: Hehe, that's the _"dust off and nuke it from orbit"_ option